# "Neither" plural agreement

Tags: verb-agreement

There are four different forms of verb pluralisation agreement I'm curious about:

1. *neither thing [has/have] an attribute*
2. *neither of the things [has/have] an attribute*
3. *both of the things [has/have] an attribute*
4. *both things [has/have] an attribute*

For each of these forms, should "have" be pluralised, or not? My intuitive guesses are singular, singular, plural and plural; but I have no specific justification.

Comment: This has been answered several times on [ELL](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+language+%26+usage+stack+exchange+neither+singular+or+plural+site:ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: _Neither_ is singular (not the one or the other), so _has_ for both (1) and (2). _Both_ is plural, so _have_ for (3) and (4).

Comment: @WeatherVane OK; can you close this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common dilemma, to which, for once, there is a definite answer.  There is ,in addition, a third such term:  *each*.

A) The terms (*neither* and *each*) are singular and so take a singular verb:  the verb/attribute applies to each singly.

B) The term *both* is plural and so takes a plural verb:  the verb/attribute applies to both *plurally*.

**BUT** There is an understandable mental urge to let proximity rather than strict grammatical number determine the grammatical number of the verb/attribute rather than the number of the strict grammatical subject.

So in your examples 1 and 2, the strict grammatical subject is singular and so the verb should follow suit: ***has***.

But in 2 the plural is often *have*, triggered by the adjacent plural noun *things*, even though it is not the strict subject. Is it an error?  In my own schooldays I would say *yes*, **but** this plural shift is now too common to render criticism churlish.  If your audience is likely to judge you or what you write adversely if it violates the strict rule, stick to it.  Otherwise don't worry.  Personally I wince to see "neither of these pupils have passed the test.", but, in the words of Clytemnestra, "an ox sits on my tongue".  It is common enough to count as established.